# Smart way to get a number of characters of longest line from ostringstream

Tags: c++, stl

I want to do something like that:

```
std::ostringstream os;
writingSomeDataToStream(os);
const size_t width = getNumberOfCharsInLongestLine(os);
const auto header = generateHeader("My diagnostic data", width);
showText(header);
showText(os.str());
```

How to write function getNumberOfCharsInLongestLine to be as fast as it is possible?

Comment: Optimal in what way? The *simplest* code would be to repeatedly call `getline` and note the length of each line, saving the largest value.

Comment: You could subclass `std::ostringstream` and count the line lengths as it is being written to maybe?

Comment: std::getline needs istream so I can't use it.

Comment: I added resolution for my problem. Maybe it is possible to write prettier piece of code.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My resolution is:

```
size_t getNumberOfCharsInLongestLine(const std::string& str)
{
    size_t longest = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (auto c : str)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            if (counter > longest)
                longest = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
          ++counter;
    }
    return longest;
}
```